# Add datauristring to file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a PDF which I am generating using jsPDF and I want to use the datauristring to upload it via my contact form 7 form. Is there a way in which I can add the datauristring value to the input file so when my form is submitted the PDF is uploaded?

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
 
doc.setFontSize(12);
doc.text(20, 15, "• Test question");
doc.text(20, 25, "Test answer");

var generatedPDF = doc.output('datauristring');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<input id="upload-select" type="file">
```